# Wine Applications Uninstalled still appear

Tags: 12.10, wine

Applications within Wine that I uninstalled still appear in the applications menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Once installed, alt-F2 and type alacarte to launch, scroll down to "wine" on the left hand side, click on the program you want to remove and click "delete".

Log out and back in again, and those icons should have gone.

Hope that helps..